# In the "Portal" games, what personality traits do the cores represent?

Tags: portal, portal-2

In the first *Portal* game, it's made quite obvious what most of the cores represent. The silent, purple one is morality, the orange one that asks constant pointless questions is curiosity and the red, growly one is anger/emotion. However, it's never made clear what the core that spouts out a cake recipe or any of the cores from the second *Portal* other than Wheatley are supposed to regulate on GLaDOS.

I just want to know what emotions/personality traits the cake core, the space core, Rick and the fact core are supposed to be for GLaDOS.

Comment: I believe the space, adventure (Rick) and fact cores were all supposed to be “corrupted”, so it may be difficult to say what their original purpose was.

Answer (score 5):

The personality cores were attached to GLaDOS in an attempt to control her, or at least provide some protection against her plans to fill the facility with neurotoxin. The fact that there was an entire bin of failed cores suggests that they tried many variations before finally settling on the ones that were stuck to her in Portal 1 - including the morality core which is apparently the only one that actually stopped her releasing the neurotoxin.

It's hard to say *why* the Aperture scientists thought that giving her large amounts of useless and inaccurate trivia, or a desire to see space, or a thirst for adventure, would do anything, but that seems to be the extent of what those cores were meant to do to her personality.

It's also odd that they would consider *those* personality aspects (if you can even call what the fact core does a personality trait) before things like anger, morality or curiousity, but then this *is* Aperture Science we're talking about, and it's quite possible that they were either proposed by, or inspired by, Cave Johnson himself. In fact, the only one of the defective cores that seems mildly plausible as a useful defence against GLaDOS releasing neurotoxin is

> the "idiot" core, aka Wheatley.